# Making authenticated request to Google Cloud Function

Tags: ruby, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have Google Cloud Function which is acceble on `https://us-central1-project.cloudfunctions.net/update`
Also I have Service Account with role 'Invoke Google Cloud Function'

First, I need to authenticate request, for this I'm using https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-ruby

I've created `google_cloud.json` for my Service Account, I'm doing

```
credentials = Google::Auth::ServiceAccountJwtHeaderCredentials.make_creds({json_key_io: File.open('./config/google_cloud.json'), scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/
cloud-platform'})
headers = {}
credentials.apply(headers)
```

output looks like

```
{:authorization=>"Bearer ENCODED_TOKEN"}
```

then I'm doing

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer ENCODED_TOKEN" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"data":["user1"]}' "https://us-central1-project.cloudfunctions.net/update"
```

And it return HTML with

```
<h2>Your client does not have permission to the requested URL <code>/update_statuses</code>.</h2>
```

If I have a VPS server that should do API requests to Google Cloud Function, how should I authorize it?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Ruby but your commands look generally correct. You'll need to use the Cloud Platform scope (`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform`). If you have `gcloud` installed, assuming your user (!) account has sufficient permissions, you can get credentials to test the `curl` command using `gcloud auth print-identity-token`. You can then `gcloud auth active-service-account` using your Service Account key to activate and then `gcloud auth print-identity-token --account=${EMAIL}` where `EMAIL` is the email address of the Service Account. If that works, the Ruby code is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got it finally. Code in the question should be used to get `Access Token`, but for calling Google Cloud Functions I need `ID Token`. For that, instead of the `scope` we need to pass function url as `target_audience`

```
google_url = 'https://us-central1-project.cloudfunctions.net/update'
path = File.join(__dir__, '../config/google_cloud.json')
authorizer = Google::Auth::ServiceAccountCredentials.make_creds(json_key_io: File.open(path), target_audience: google_url)
token = authorizer.apply({})[:authorization]
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @DazWilkin, enable the service account by running `gcloud auth print-identity-token` then to get an identity token, you can `gcloud auth print-identity-token --account=${ACCOUNT}` where `ACCOUNT` is the email address of the service account.

You may refer to [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account) for more details.

Comment: thanks, token from this command works. will try to figure out how can I get it from code